# Oracle: INSERT values from SELECT...JOIN, SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values

Tags: oracle, join, insert, ora-00947

I'm trying to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(a, b, c)
SELECT a FROM source1
JOIN source2 ON ...
```

Where source2 contains columns B and C.

However Oracle doesn't seem to like this and is telling me "SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values".

Am I doing something wrong here? Is this syntax even possible? Or do I have to rewrite it as:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM source1, source2 WHERE ....
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use as many identifiers in the SELECT clause as in the INSERT clause, as in:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(a, b, c)
SELECT s1.a, s2.b, s2.c FROM source1 s1
  JOIN source2 s2 ON ...
```

Comment: This might be what I need...let me give it a try.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks Vincent!

Answer (score 1):

The select needs to return the same number of columns as you listed in the `INSERT` statement.

So: yes, you need to rewrite the query to `SELECT a,b,c FROM ...`